# Redirecting subdomain to file without hardcoding url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

Actually topic is simple and answered million times but, somehow doesn't work on me.
What I try to do is redirect "m.domain.com"  and "mob.domain.com" to a file "domain.com/folder/mobile.htm"
But looks like any code conflicts with my current code which removes "www" from beginning.

My current code is

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|off
    RewriteCond http%1://%{HTTP_HOST} ^(https?://)(www\.)?(.+)$
        RewriteRule ^ %1%3%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# this is for webmail forward #
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /mail/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule . /webmail/ [L]
```

How can I redirect m and mob domains without conflicting with this code and without hardcoding "domain.com" ?

Thanks for your helps in advance.

Comment: My problem, I'm not familiar with htaccess coding. The current code I use is also found with a search. After testing it, I started to use. Any suggestions welcomes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this rule **on top of** your existing rules just below `RewriteEngine On` line:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s on(s)|
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:m|mob)\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http%1://%2/folder/mobile.htm [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I need to solve the problem without hardcoding the domain. Like in my example. I update many locations with some blocked IP updates. That's why harcoding is not possible for me as I mentioned in question.

Comment: Didn't work :(
I think my problem is something else. It's giving error "ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED" I tried in different combinations to be sure but, no...

Actually I dont have subdomains like m or mob. I was just trying to simulate it but, seems I can not override it with htaccess.  Or maybe I think wrong. I would like to take your opinions. Where I do mistake???

Comment: Ok if hostname is not valid then its not really mod_rewrite problem. For simulation you will need to create those fake host entries in `/etc/hosts/` file and then try these rules.

Comment: So simulate just with htaccess is not possible...  Ok I got it. Now I understood my problem.  Thanks for your reply.